# WPF render controls in the background

Tags: wpf, background

I have an application that has a view area.  In the view area contains a grid that will contain a collection of controls, such as images, list views, data grids and text.

One one view will be visible at a time, since there is only one view area.  Currently when the action is performed to make a new view active I render the view and set it as a child to the view area.  Some views takes up to a couple of second to render, so there is a latency here.

I would like to render all 10 views when the application is first loaded and then just grab the appropriate view when called upon.  I have not been able to do this.  A lot of my view items are usign proportional sizes, the grid uses the Star for the row and column sizes, so it appears that until the view is bound to a visable area where it can calculate all of its sizing it doesn't actual perform any rendering.

For instance, my data grids still flick as it opens it with all of the columns set to 20 width and then it snaps them to the correct widths after.  You can visually notice this on the screen, an intial draw with narrow columns and then they all expand to fill the data grid area.

I want to do all rending in the background, then once it is finished display the final product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A control cannot perform final rendering until it has a container. Maybe try hosting the views differently.  Maybe build your views as pages and host the pages in a frame.  I don't guarantee that will be faster but something to look at.  Could you use tab?  I am pretty sure a tabitem reuses the last rendering or at least pieces of the last rendering.   Optimize your individual views.  A GridView is typically faster than a DataGrid but may not have the features you need.  For a table where I need speed I use a GridView and set the column widths based on the data - 100 rows and 40 columns renders in than 1.0 seconds and I put it in a tabitem and if I come back to the tab (after it has rendered once) it renders in 0.1 seconds.  If a view has a lot of data that scrolls then try virtualization.  Or load multiple frames in the same column / row and only have one visible at at time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try having a separate view area that is the same size as the main one but that is hidden behind the main one, and put all of your 10 views as children of that one so that they render with the appropriate sizes, then swap them out into the main one as necessary...